# TypeScript equivalent of PropTypes.array and PropTypes.object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the TypeScript equivalent of this?

```
sessions: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.array,
    PropTypes.object,
]).isRequired,
```

I translated this to the following 'point':

```
export type Sessions = [Object | Array];
```

However, I'm not sure how I should replace PropTypes.array and PropTypes.object.

Answer (score 1):

Like any other type

```
static propTypes = {
    sessions: Array | Object
}
```

If session is an array of either type (but it's not what is stated in the PropTypes expression):

```
sessions: (Array | Object)[]
```

If it's not required:

```
sessions?: Array | Object
```

typeless Array can also be expressed as `[]`.

`(Object | Array)[]` can also be expressed as `Array<Object | Array>`.

In some case Object can also be expressed as `{}` and this way can declare props: `{a: number, b: string}`

As explained here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score 0):

You can consider this

```
type TypeSessions = Object | Array;
const sessions: TypeSessions = [];
```